# How many 1's can a regular 0,1-matrix contain?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix of order $n$ has all of its entries in $\{0,1\}$. What is the maximum number of $1$ in the matrix for which the matrix is non singular.

Comment: It is at least $n^2-(n-1)$. Consider the matrix with ones everywhere and $0$ on its diagonal except for one diagonal element. I would not be surprised if this is also the upper bound.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 11):

Suppose that the matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$, by the pigeon hole principle if $A$ has strictly more than $n^2-(n-1)$ nonzero entries, then at least two columns are full of ones and thus are linearly dependent. It follows then that $A$ has not full rank (and thus is singular). Now, the matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ defined by $$A_{i,j}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } i \neq j \\ 1 & \text{if } i=j=n\\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases}$$
is nonsingular and thus the bound you are looking for is $n^2-(n-1)=n^2-n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $n^2-n+1$. Let $v=e_1+\cdots+e_n$, where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ is the standard orthonormal basis. Then the matrix with row vectors $\{v, v-e_1, \cdots, v-e_{n-1}\}$ is a matrix containing the maximum number of 1 for which it is nonsingular.